# Blue Screen error BAD_POOL_CALLER 0x000000C2

Tags: windows-xp, bsod

My computer was working fine for months but now when it starts up the Windows XP screen comes up to show the computer is starting up but then a blue screen appears with the error below:

BAD_POOL_CALLER

STOP: 0x000000C2 (0x00000043, 0xDB3C6000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000)

I have tried booting off the Windows XP CD and trying to do a re-installation but when the setup try's to query the disk the setup crashes and exists.

I've run diags and that says everything is fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have tried switching both memory modules with another working machine's memory which is exactly the same model etc.

I have also switched the hard drive but neither made any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I was getting bsod's like these it turned out to be a faulty memory module. Have you tried running [Memtest86](http://www.memtest.org/)?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bad memory to me. Before changing the modules it would be worth a try to clean the contacts on them with isopropyl alcohol and give them a gentle rub to get rid of any oxidation. Also if running in a dual-channel mode make sure you are using exactly the same modules in each paired slot.

Answer (score 0):

You're experiencing the problem due to several reasons- such as corrupt OS files, recent hardware changes, incorrect system settings, corrupt cache contents and other reasons. Repair your system files through System File Checker tool, disconnect recently connected hardware, revert-back newly applied system settings and delete temporary files and cache contents.

[Download Hotfix](http://smitalandvikas.com/reginout) and check if the problem still persists. Alternatively, perform manual steps given below until your problem is completely fixed. The actual steps are given below:

Step 1: Repair System Files

1. Insert Windows OS installation disc.
2. Click the Start button, point to All Programs | Accessories.
3. Right click Command Prompt, choose Run as administrator.
4. Type the following command-
   SFC /SCANNOW
5. Press ENTER.
6. Reboot your PC when you're done.

Step 2: Disconnect Recently Installed Hardware

Disconnect any recently installed hardware devices. Check for "Compatible for Windows" logo on the hardware package.

Step 3: Delete Cache Contents

1. Click Start, point to All Programs | Accessories.
2. Select Disk CleanUp.
3. Select a disk drive, click OK.

Step 4: Restore Recent Settings

1. Click Start, point to All Programs | Accessories.
2. Select System Restore.
3. Click Next, follow the on-screen wizard.